# Code completion is not working on Flash Builder 4.7 project

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a project and added a library to it and none of the classes in the library are showing in auto complete / code hinting in MXML. I searched online and read that increasing the memory might help, allowing the type caching to be larger, but I can't find the eclipse.ini or flashbuilder.ini file that they all talk about. I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.

Also, if there is a way to force eclipse to recreate the type cache (classes list) I would rather try that first than mess with the ini file.

Comment: `FlashBuilder.ini` should reside in FB's installation directory, e.g. `c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)`

Answer (score 1):

I had to select the FlashBuilder icon and choose "Expand or Show package contents" and then it showed more folders. In those folders was the FlashBuilder.ini.